# Let $\displaystyle X \sim f(x\mid \theta) = (\theta/2)^{\lvert x \rvert}(1-\theta)^{1-\lvert x \rvert}$

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation

Let $\displaystyle X \sim f(x\mid \theta) = (\theta/2)^{\lvert x \rvert}(1-\theta)^{1-\lvert x \rvert}1_{(x\in \{ -1,0,1 \})}1_{(0 \le \theta \le 1)}$ and let $T(X) = 2\cdot1_{(X=1)}$

I will omit the indicator functions for sake of brevity.

I am trying to find $E[T(X) \mid \lvert X \rvert ]$

For the conditional probabilities:

$\displaystyle P(T(X) = k \mid \lvert X \rvert = j ) = \frac{P(T(X) =k,\lvert X \rvert= j)}{P(\lvert X \rvert= j)}, k = 0,2; j = -1,0,1$

I am having difficulty computing an expression for this conditional probability for the conditional expectation. I know $T(X)$ is unbiased for $\theta$, i.e. $E[T(X)]=\theta$ so it should be that $E[E[T(X) \mid \lvert X \rvert ]] = \theta$

The issue is that $T(X)$ is dependent on $X$ so having trouble with $P(T(X) =k,\lvert X \rvert= j)$

Comment: Since $E\left[|X|\right]=\theta$, the conditional expectation equals $|X|$ by Lehmann-Scheffe theorem.

Comment: @StubbornAtom how does that follow from Lehmann-Scheffe theorem?

Comment: Because this is the UMVUE and UMVUE is unique.

Comment: @StubbornAtom if it were the conditional variance can I use a similar method?

Comment: Forget Lehmann-Scheffe. You have $h(y)=E\left [T(X)\mid |X|=y\right]=2P(X=1\mid |X|=y)$, which equals $1$ if $y=1$ and $0$ if $y=0$. This is just $y$ since $y$ takes only the values $0$ and $1$. The answer is thus $h(Y)=Y=|X|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of notation, let $Y = |X|$. We have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[T(X) | Y] &= \underbrace{\mathbb{E}[T(X) | Y = 0]}_{=0}\mathbb{P}(Y = 0) + \mathbb{E}[T(X) | Y = 1]\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(Y = 1)}_{=\theta} \\
&=\theta\cdot\mathbb{E}[T(X) | Y = 1]
\end{align*}
But then $P(X = -1|Y=1) = P(X = 1|Y=1) = \frac{1}{2}$. So $\mathbb{E}[T(X) | Y = 1] = 2\mathbb{P}(X=1|Y=1) = 1$. Therefore, $\mathbb{E}[T(X) | Y] = \theta$.

Comment: You found $E[T(X)]$ instead of $E[T(X)\mid Y]$.

Comment: The answer should be a function of $y$ since $E[T(X)\mid Y]$ is a random variable.

Comment: Sorry, in any case, we would have $\mathbb{E}[T(X)|Y] = 0$ if $Y=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[T(X)|Y] = 1$ if $Y = 1$.